# Class Design Principles PHP MongoDB

Tags: php, oop, mongodb

I'm working on developing an API.  Started with a concept last year and have been developing on it since then.  Over the course of the year, the structure and offerings have changed greatly and I am finding it a headache to update my class structures.  Granted, I started designing this new to PHP and MongoDB, also new to the concept of web programming and servers getting and sending data and databases in general.  I have a decent understanding of how the two work together now, but I believe my initial approach to class design is wrong.  Well, I guess not wrong, but not designed as well as it should be.

Currently, I have 4 main classes.  We'll call them class A, B, C, and D.
Now, class A, B, and C are all objects that represent the documents that are stored in 3 separate MongoDB Collections.  Class D represents a monster class that handles interactions between the other three objects.  I felt it was wrong to have objects modifying other objects inside of them.

Objects A, B, and C all have connections to MongoDB inside of their __construct() function.  Is this a correct approach?  Is it good practice to have object handle their own connection to the database?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Where do you store your database connection information? In classes A, B, and C?

Comment: Yes, they are all properties of the objects A, B, and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally a bad idea unless you have a pooling connection manager from which objects acquire their connections. Connection setup is expensive, and you have a finite number of connection slots.

Generally speaking, you'll want one connection per thread, which objects then use. This may be varied based on your application's needs, but at a minimum, use a connection pool rather than one connection per instance.

Comment: So, you are saying to make a class that is just a connection and send it the collection name depending on the need of the connection?

Comment: Likely, yes. You want to avoid doing connection setup if at all possible, so re-using connections is ideal. A connection pool that objects check out from would effectively do this, as well.